# Find button in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

[image]

I would like to get some information about this button, either if it's clickable or the text inside it, doesn't matter as long as I get something from it. This is what I tried and it feels like no matter what I try Im either getting an error or `None`.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml', from_encoding='utf-8')
button = soup.find('button', {'class': 'btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block btn-leading-ficon add-to-cart-button'})
```

Could this be because the button is generated by JavaScript or something like that?

Comment: If the button is generated dynamically, BS won't find it. You need to use Selenium Webdriver.

Comment: Could you provide some more information: url, code, errir please - make it easier to reproduce.

Comment: @Barmar That's what I figured. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `class_` argument in your `soup.find()` function:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml', from_encoding='utf-8')
button = soup.find('button', class_= 'btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block btn-leading-ficon add-to-cart-button')
```